# Bootstrap/jQuery radio buttons don't work on Firefox/Safari

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firefox, radio-button

I have a Bootstrap radio buttons for showing/hiding parts of the content, and it works perfectly on Chrome, but doesnt work on Firefox nor Safari (iPhone, iPad...). It shows all content by default - even though 4 of 5 rows should be hidden onload.

Also, I'm getting these two errors on Firefox (they do not show up on Chrome):

```
TypeError: t is undefined[Learn More]
bootstrap.min.js:6:2080

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined[Learn More]
togglebuttons.js:115:1
```

It is a WordPress site with one of the most popular paid themes on the market, so I'm guessing there shouldn't be any problems with jQuery, but it seems there is. What could be the cause?

When I tried to load jQuery manually just before I load the script from the snippet below, page wouldn't even load, because I was getting some jQuery conflicts.

Here's the code:

```js
(function($) {
    var $first_visible = 1;
    var $second_visible = 0;
    var $third_visible = 0;
    var $fourth_visible = 0;
    var $fifth_visible = 0;

    // hide all except the first one implicitly
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#row2').hide('1');
        $('#row3').hide('1');
        $('#row4').hide('1');
        $('#row5').hide('1');
    });


    $("input[name=options]").change(function () {
        if(this.value == "1") {
            if($second_visible) {
                $('#row2').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row1').fadeIn('200'); });
                $second_visible = 0;
            }
            else if($third_visible) {
                $('#row3').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row1').fadeIn('200'); });
                $third_visible = 0;
            }
            else if($fourth_visible) {
                $('#row4').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row1').fadeIn('200'); });
                $fourth_visible = 0;
            }
            else if($fifth_visible) {
                $('#row5').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row1').fadeIn('200'); });
                $fifth_visible = 0;
            }
            $first_visible = 1;
        }
        else if(this.value == "2") {
            if($first_visible) {
                $('#row1').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row2').fadeIn('200'); });
                $first_visible = 0;
            }
            else if($third_visible) {
                $('#row3').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row2').fadeIn('200'); });
                $third_visible = 0;
            }
            else if($fourth_visible) {
                $('#row4').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row2').fadeIn('200'); });
                $fourth_visible = 0;
            }
            else if($fifth_visible) {
                $('#row5').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row2').fadeIn('200'); });
                $fifth_visible = 0;
            }
            $second_visible = 1;
        }
        else if(this.value == "3") {
            if($first_visible) {
                $('#row1').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row3').fadeIn('200'); });
                $first_visible = 0;
            }
            else if($second_visible) {
                $('#row2').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row3').fadeIn('200'); });
                $second_visible = 0;
            }
            else if($fourth_visible) {
                $('#row4').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row3').fadeIn('200'); });
                $fourth_visible = 0;
            }
            else if($fifth_visible) {
                $('#row5').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row3').fadeIn('200'); });
                $fifth_visible = 0;
            }
            $third_visible = 1;
        }
        else if(this.value == "4") {
            if($first_visible) {
                $('#row1').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row4').fadeIn('200'); });
                $first_visible = 0;
            }
            else if($second_visible) {
                $('#row2').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row4').fadeIn('200'); });
                $second_visible = 0;
            }
            else if($third_visible) {
                $('#row3').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row4').fadeIn('200'); });
                $third_visible = 0;
            }
            else if($fifth_visible) {
                $('#row5').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row4').fadeIn('200'); });
                $fifth_visible = 0;
            }
            $fourth_visible = 1;
        }
        else if(this.value == "5") {
            if($first_visible) {
                $('#row1').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row5').fadeIn('200'); });
                $first_visible = 0;
            }
            else if($second_visible) {
                $('#row2').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row5').fadeIn('200'); });
                $second_visible = 0;
            }
            else if($third_visible) {
                $('#row3').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row5').fadeIn('200'); });
                $third_visible = 0;
            }
            else if($fourth_visible) {
                $('#row4').fadeOut('200', function() { $('#row5').fadeIn('200'); });
                $fourth_visible = 0;
            }
            $fifth_visible = 1;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- TOGGLE BUTTONS -->
 <div class="row togglebuttons-row">
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-success btn-primary active">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" value="1" checked><span class="radio-span">Show 1</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-success btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" value="2"><span class="radio-span">Show 2</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-success btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off" value="3"><span class="radio-span">Show 3</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-success btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off" value="4"><span class="radio-span">Show 4</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-success btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option5" autocomplete="off" value="5"><span class="radio-span">Show 5</span>
    </label>
  </div><!-- btn-group -->
 </div><!-- row -->



 <!-- *************************************
 ********** GENEROVANIE KONTAKTOV ********* -->

 <div class="row row-eq-height contact-list" id="row1">
  hello 1
 </div><!-- row1 -->

 <div class="row row-eq-height contact-list" id="row2">
  hello 2
 </div><!-- row2 -->

 <div class="row row-eq-height contact-list" id="row3">
  hello 3
 </div><!-- row3 -->

 <div class="row row-eq-height contact-list" id="row4">
  hello 4
 </div><!-- row4 -->

 <div class="row row-eq-height contact-list" id="row5">
  hello 5
 </div><!-- row5 -->
```

Comment: Looks like jQuery is not loaded. Check your browser's dev tools and the network tab: what response are you getting when requesting the jQuery library?

Comment: It works on my FF

Comment: does it work when you load your code at the bottom of you page?

Comment: @Terry I'm getting 200 codes for all jquery loads. However, it is jQuery v1.12.4, isn't that too old? But I am using the newest version of WP and the theme.

Comment: @PatrickCyiza What do you mean by "your code"? Do you mean <script>s? Yes, I load them right before the closing </body> tag.

Comment: If the theme is coded correctly, it should have requested the correct version of jQuery :)

Comment: also check if you can call jQuery in your console after your page is loaded.

Comment: @PatrickCyiza How do I check this? In network tab, the jquery.js is being loaded way before my custom.js, containing the code above. Is that it?

Comment: @KristiánFilo in the Dev tools of your browser you should have a js console... but I'll admit I don't know how to access said Dev tools on safari iOS or if they even have one.

Comment: @PatrickCyiza OK, I can confirm - Firefox is NOT loading jQuery, while Chrome is. But I have no clue why.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I finally figured it out. The problem was that jQuery was loading on Chrome (somehow), but was not loading on Firefox nor Apple devices.

I was loading my script at the end of the file the traditional way, using `<script>` tags inside .php body. When I used the proper way for WordPress, it finally seem to work. I used this code in my theme's functions.php file:

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/myscript.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
```

Comment: I guess it must be the way each browser handle cross site scripting.